# How to delete Javascript object property?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete a object property which is shallow copy of another object.
But the problem arises when I try to delete it, it never goes off while original value throws expected output.

```js
var obj = {
    name:"Tom"
};

var newObj = Object.create(obj);
delete newObj.name;//It never works!

console.log(newObj.name);//name is still there
```

Comment: Both are completely different objects! Not `referenced`!

Comment: With `var newObj = obj;` It would work as you are expecting!

Comment: From docs, _The Object.create() method creates a "new object"_

Comment: Notice that `newObj` has *no*  `name` property, so your delete is useless on it. It is `newObj`'s prototype === `obj`, which has the `name` property... or not if you deleted it...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`newObj` inherits from `obj`.

You can delete the property by accessing the parent object:

```
delete Object.getPrototypeOf(newObj).name;
```

(which changes the parent object)

You can also shadow it, by setting the value to `undefined` (for example):

```
newObj.name = undefined;
```

But you can't remove the property on newObj without deleting it from the parent object as the prototype is looked up the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) until it is found.

Comment: But usage of `_proto_` is not recommended. Isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure there's really a notable difference when using it read only but yes it's the recommended practice now.

Comment: Thanks Denys for the quick reply, it is working now.

Answer (score 4):

Basically `Object.create` will create an object , set its prototype as per the passed object and it will return it. So if you want to `delete` any property from the returned object of `Object.create`, you have to access its prototype.

```
var obj = { name:"Tom" };
var newObj = Object.create(obj);
delete Object.getPrototypeOf(newObj).name
console.log(newObj.name); //undefined.
```

Comment: In the Chrome console, the OP's code works fine: no need to use prototype.

Comment: @manuell I am using chrome and it is not working as intended.

Comment: You are right. I was running the `delete obj.name;` line, too. Without that one, `name` is still here in newObj (sort of), indeed.

Comment: The downvote is not mine. I just upvoted, and the downvote is still here.

Comment: @manuell Oh Thats's fine. keep encouraging our peers mate. :)